# Extracting an int value from a column depending on other column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe on Pandas, which contains information from FC Barcelona soccer matches and results.

`df['Match Result']` contains info such as '2:0'.

I already did the split and I have two columns for the results of both teams.
I named them `['Left']` and `['Right']`, in int values.

Now, if Barcelona is playing away, the goal count for the team will be shown in `['Right']`. Else (if playing home), it will be shown on `['Left']`. The new int column `df['Barcelona_result']` must contain the int values from `['Left']` or `['Right']` depending if `['Location']` value (string) is 'Home' or 'Away'

So, I tried something like this:

```
df['Barcelona_result']= 0
df['Barcelona_result'] = df['Barcelona_result'].astype('int')

for i in df['Location']
    if i == "Home":
       df.Barcelona_result += df.Left
    else: df.Barcelona_result += df.Right
       break
```

The home results are OK but the away results are not. It's always taking the int values from `['Left']`. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected ouput?

Comment: ...and format the code with proper indentation. It makes a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably do it like this:

```
#split the result
res = df['Match Result'].astype(str).str.split(":")

#default Home
df['Barcelona_result'] = res.str[0]
#mask with second split if Location not "Home"
df['Barcelona_result'] = df['Barcelona_result'].mask(df['Location]!="Home", res.str[1])
#convert to int
df['Barcelona_result'] = df['Barcelona_result'].astype(int)
```

This code is under the assumption that you always have results. If you have missing or misformatted results it might err.